# Cefsharp Oncontextmenucommand Get Menu Label

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, cefsharp

Alright so I have this code in my program to add menu items in context menu and perform action when they are clicked

```
Private Sub IContextMenuHandler_OnBeforeContextMenu(browserControl As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame, parameters As IContextMenuParams, model As IMenuModel) Implements IContextMenuHandler.OnBeforeContextMenu
    ''Add new custom menu items
    model.AddItem(DirectCast(Copy, CefMenuCommand), "Copy Link Address")
    model.AddItem(CType(26504, CefMenuCommand), "Display alert message")

    Dim viewMenu As IMenuModel = model.AddSubMenu(CType(26505, CefMenuCommand), "View")
    viewMenu.AddRadioItem(CType(26506, CefMenuCommand), "Large icons", 0)
    viewMenu.AddRadioItem(CType(26507, CefMenuCommand), "Medium icons", 0)
    viewMenu.AddRadioItem(CType(26508, CefMenuCommand), "Small icons", 0)
    viewMenu.AddSeparator()

End Sub

Private Function IContextMenuHandler_OnContextMenuCommand(browserControl As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame, parameters As IContextMenuParams, commandId As CefMenuCommand, eventFlags As CefEventFlags) As Boolean Implements IContextMenuHandler.OnContextMenuCommand
    Try
        If CInt(commandId) = Copy Then
            If (parameters.LinkUrl.Length > 0) Then
                Clipboard.SetText(parameters.LinkUrl)
            End If
        End If

        If commandId = CType(26504, CefMenuCommand) Then
            Clipboard.SetText(imn.GetLabel(CType(26504, CefMenuCommand)))
            browserControl.Paste()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ''MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return False
End Function
```

How do I get the label of the menu item (in Oncontextmenucommand function) which was clicked ? How do I access the IMenuModel because it has a getlabel function.

Regards,

Comment: There is no API for that, you could easily add your own dictionary for lookup.

Comment: By dictionary you mean dictionary(of key,pair)? So I add the menus and add the int code and label in a dictionary and then cmpare int code and get the label right? Another question - Do all these int codes have to be more than 26500? I couldn't find answer to this.

Comment: A generic dictionary, yes. Your custom items need to be between user first and last entries see http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/T_CefSharp_CefMenuCommand.htm

Comment: just curious what happens when the limit of 28,500 is breached? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: You would have to look at the Chromium source. I've never had reason to add 2000 menu items

Comment: oh ok nevermind. Thanks for help though. Dictionary method worked.